# Transfering files from a zip to a jar

Tags: java, jar, zip

I've been troubled for the past 3 days now by an annoying problem, I do not have the faintest clue on how i could possibly transfer files from a zip to a jar. I'm not sure whether or not i need to supply a buffer to said process, and whether i use the JarInput/OutputStream or i instead use Enumerations, I've done some research on how to do it and i cannot find anything apart from a big paste of code, as you can tell i would much prefer an explanation of what i need to do as a pose to how to do it.

Basically i would just like a nice simple, yes informative tutorial on how i could transfer the contents of lets so "foo.zip" into "bar.jar". ("bar.jar" already contains files which i do not want to delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transfer *all* files from zip to jar you just have to rename zip to jar because jar is a zip format.

EDIT:
If you want to copy some entries from zip/jar to other zip/jar or to copy entries to existing zip/jar you have to iterate over entries in input file using `ZipInputStream`, read the entries and write them to output `ZipOutputStream`.  Take a look on this tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/. It explains everything in details and contains code samples.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look into that. (i would accept but for some reason SO won't allow me to accept the answer until 10 minutes after the question has been asked)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just rename the file from `foo.zip` to `foo.jar`. I'm not kidding!

You can read and write `zip` and `jar` files with [java.util.zi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)p, `jar` files are really just `zip` files.

Comment: `bar.jar` already contains files. He wants to **add** the files of `foo.zip`.

Comment: I am aware that zip files are just Jar files with manifests and such, but i don't know how to add the contents of a zip to a jar without deleting the already existing files

Comment: @Sirko - yes and the answer is java.util.zip